# jQuery Droppable drop event function not running

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm creating a list where the user can update the order by dragging text into small boxes. I'm outputting most of the DOM using jQuery instead of HTML. Currently the items are draggable, and I stated to show an alert when an item is dragged inside a box, but no dice. Below is my code, can some one tell me if I'm doing something wrong?

```
$('.sequence_option').draggable();

  $('.sequencing').append('<div class="sequence_boxes"></div>');

  $('.sequence_option').each(function(i) {
    $('<div class="box"></div>').appendTo($('.sequence_boxes'));

  });


$(".box").droppable({
    accept: ".sequence_option",
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
      alert("dropped");
    }
  });
```

Comment: It looks like your doing the drop alert correct. see this fiddle example from your code here http://jsfiddle.net/matt9388/67tZS/1/

Comment: Do you want the alert to show when you ***drag*** the item into the box or when you ***drop*** the item into the box? You're using the drop event so it should not trigger when you drag into the box. However, when you release the mouse button and the drop function is performed, the drop event should fire and the alert should show as @Matt's example above does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know since you didn't post your CSS, but the answer is probably that your `.sequence_option` elements aren't styled to have a limited width. By default block elements like `div`s span 100% of their container width. Unless you set your `droppable`'s tolerances to accept smaller overlaps, it's probable that your `.sequence_option` draggable elements aren't being completely contained within the `.box` droppable.

**EDIT**

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palpatim/2PVXL/).

Remove the CSS `width` declaration on `.sequence_option` to watch the width span the container and the drop not get triggered.

```
.box {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #666;
    margin: 10px;
}

.sequence_option {
    /* Remove this line to watch it break */
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
}
```